# Copy range of cells from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small VBA excel script to copy selected range of data from multiple workbooks into one worksheet.
Where I am trying to copy a range of data from source-range to destination range. The destination is dynamically calculated for each iteration based on cells/range copied in the previous iteration.

of interest and the piece of code that does not work is

```
rng = "C" & rowNum & ":" & "C" & rowRange
myWorksheet.Range(rng).Value = .Range("A8:A17")

' Copy Estimates for each Role  does not work
rng = "G" & rowNum & ":" & "G" & rowRange
myWorksheet.Range(rng).Value = .Range("B8:A17")
```

The complete file is also listed below.

I have multiple workbooks in the following format

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | t1 | a6 | a7 | a8 |
| 3 | t2 | a10 | a11 | a12 |
| 4 | t3 | a14 | a15 | a16 |
| 5 | t4 | a18 | a19 | a20 |

...

...

...

File2

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p2 |  |  |  |
| 2 | t8 | b6 | b7 | b8 |
| 3 | t9 | b10 | b11 | b12 |
| 4 | t10 | b14 | b15 | b16 |
| 5 | t11 | b18 | b19 | b20 |

...

...

...

File3 ...

File4 ...

The expected output:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | t1 | a6 | a8 |
| 2 | p1 | t2 | a10 | a12 |
| 3 | p1 | t3 | a14 | a16 |
| 4 | p1 | t4 | a18 | a20 |
| 5 | p2 | t8 | b6 | a8 |
| 6 | p2 | t9 | b10 | a12 |
| 7 | p2 | t10 | b14 | a16 |
| 8 | p2 | t11 | b18 | a20 |

...

...

...

---

```
Sub ExtractDataFromMultipleFiles()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim srcFile As Variant
    Dim fileCount As Integer
    Dim rng As Variant
    
    filePath = "D:\Excel_VBA\PullEstimates\Project Estimates\"
    srcFile = Dir$(filePath & "*.xlsx")

    i = 0
    Set myWorksheet = Sheets("EstimatesMerged")
    Do While srcFile <> ""
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & srcFile)
        With wBook.Sheets("Budget Project Estimate")
            rowNum = i * 10 + 2
            rowRange = rowNum + 9
            'Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B1").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
            ' Copy Project Name
            
            myWorksheet.Range("B" & rowNum).Value = .Range("A1")
         
            ' Copy titles  does not work
            rng = "C" & rowNum & ":" & "C" & rowRange
            myWorksheet.Range(rng).Value = .Range("A8:A17")
            
         
            ' Copy Estimates for each Role  does not work
            rng = "G" & rowNum & ":" & "G" & rowRange
            myWorksheet.Range(rng).Value = .Range("B8:A17")
        End With
        wBook.Close True
        srcFile = Dir$
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set wBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect you may have a typo when copying estimates for each 'Role'.  `.Range("B8:A17")` should be `.Range("B8:B17")...true?

Comment: Also, try assigning the `Value` to the `Range`...like,  `myWorksheet.Range(rng) = .Range("A8:A17").Value`

Comment: @BZngr yes .Range("B8:A17") should be `.Range("B8:B17")
myWorksheet.Range(rng) = .Range("A8:A17").Value  did not work.